# Set and get catalog session display mode via JS

Tags: magento-enterprise, catalog, theme, javascript

I want set and get display_mode variable in `catalog/session` via javascript in magento.

In PHP we can use:

```
$mode = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getDisplayMode();
```

How can I do it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to set up your own controller with actions that get and set this value, then you can simply fire off a request in your JavaScript and that should work nicely for you.